# Variable name in an anonymous inner class can be the same as a parameter outside of class. Why?

Tags: java, android

I call the method doWork and pass it a parameter with the name **myString**. In the anonymous inner AsyncTask class, the method onPostExecute defines another String with the same name, **myString**, as the param passed to doWork.

```
// Note the parameter variable name (i.e. myString)
private void doWork(final String myString) {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            // Why is this declaration allowed?
            String myString = "myString";            
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

Why does Java allow this? Usually, Java complains if you define a variable with a name that already exists in the same scope. What is going on internally that makes the compiler accept this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable `myString` that you have defined inside your `onPostExecute` is a method-level local variable . So it's scope is just inside `onPostExecute` method and not outside it.

So it does not clash/interfere with your earlier variable defined outisde the method `onPostExecute`.

This is a very simple explanation of it.

**EDIT : Further explanation**

Let take this example and it might help you clear your doubt.

```
class MyClass{
    public String myString = "class level string";

    public void test(String testString){
         String myString = "method level string";
         // you have shadowed the class level variable by defining a method-level local variable.

         System.out.println(myString);  // will print "method level string"
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but the myString passed a param also has scope inside onPostExecute. It's declared final so I can access its value inside onPostExecute.

Comment: Looking at your code, I thought there was NO WAY that could compile. It just seems like something Java would complain about. I thought I had found some weird behavior with inner classes and such but it looks like you're 100% right given your simple and straightforward example; it's method-level local scope that explains it all. Thanks, @Abubakkar!